# What does the following structure mean and how to implement this structure in matlab？

Tags: analog-to-digital

[image]

[image]

Looking forward to explaining what this structure means, and the relationship between the two structures.

Paper: [An Efficient Spur-Aliasing-Free Spectral Calibration Technique in Time-Interleaved ADCs](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=9011576)

Comment: They are block diagrams.  Are you saying you don't know how to read block diagrams?

Comment: How to implement the correlation filter in Figure 7? The paper only mentioned using the architecture in Figure 8, but I don't know how to implement it.

Comment: I don't understand the principle of correlation filter, why the output is ILk?

Comment: Then please _edit your question_ so that it is clear that you don't understand the principle of a correlation filter.  You may also want to trim out the "how to implement it in Matlab" part -- getting the math right and implementing the math are two different things, and the first step to implementation is understanding the math.